# How does the while works in case of Filehandle when reading a gigantic file in Perl

Tags: perl, while-loop, filehandle

I have a very large file to read, so when I use `while` for reading it line by line, the script starts taking more time to read the line as I dig deep in the file; and to mention the rise is exponential.

```
while (<$fh>)
{do something}
```

Does `while` has to parse through all the lines it has already read to go to the next unread line or something like that?

How can I overcome such a situation?

### EDIT 1:

My code:

```
$line=0;
%values;
open my $fh1, '<', "file.xml" or die $!;
while (<$fh1>)
{
$line++;
if ($_=~ s/foo//gi)
{
    chomp $_;
    $values{'id'} = $_;
}
elsif ($_=~ s/foo//gi)
{
    chomp $_;
    $values{'type'} = $_;
}
elsif ($_=~ s/foo//gi)
{
    chomp $_;
    $values{'pattern'} = $_;
}
if (keys(%values) == 3)
{
    open FILE, ">>temp.txt" or die $!;
    print FILE "$values{'id'}\t$values{'type'}\t$values{'pattern'}\n";
    close FILE;
    %values = ();
}
if($line == ($line1+1000000))
{
    $line1=$line;
    $read_time = time();
    $processing_time = $read_time - $start_time - $processing_time;
    print "xml file parsed till line $line, time taken $processing_time sec\n";
}
}
```

### EDIT 2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Entrezgene-Set PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD NCBI-Entrezgene, 21st January 2005//EN"   "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/data_specs/dtd/NCBI_Entrezgene.dtd">
<Entrezgene-Set>

<Entrezgene>
<Entrezgene_track-info>
<Gene-track>
  <Gene-track_geneid>816394</Gene-track_geneid>
  <Gene-track_create-date>
    <Date>
      <Date_std>
        <Date-std>
          <Date-std_year>2003</Date-std_year>
          <Date-std_month>7</Date-std_month>
          <Date-std_day>30</Date-std_day>
          <Date-std_hour>19</Date-std_hour>
          <Date-std_minute>53</Date-std_minute>
          <Date-std_second>0</Date-std_second>
        </Date-std>
      </Date_std>
    </Date>
  </Gene-track_create-date>
  <Gene-track_update-date>
    <Date>
      <Date_std>
        <Date-std>
          <Date-std_year>2015</Date-std_year>
          <Date-std_month>1</Date-std_month>
          <Date-std_day>8</Date-std_day>
          <Date-std_hour>15</Date-std_hour>
          <Date-std_minute>41</Date-std_minute>
          <Date-std_second>0</Date-std_second>
        </Date-std>
      </Date_std>
    </Date>
  </Gene-track_update-date>
</Gene-track>
</Entrezgene_track-info>
<Entrezgene_type value="protein-coding">6</Entrezgene_type>
<Entrezgene_source>
<BioSource>
  <BioSource_genome value="chromosome">21</BioSource_genome>
  <BioSource_org>
    <Org-ref>
      <Org-ref_taxname>Arabidopsis thaliana</Org-ref_taxname>
      <Org-ref_common>thale cress</Org-ref_common>
      <Org-ref_db>
        <Dbtag>
          <Dbtag_db>taxon</Dbtag_db>
```

This is just a jest of the original xml file, if you like you can check the whole xml file from [Here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=viridiplantae). Select any one entry and send it to file as xml file.

### EDIT 3

As suggested by many pioneers that I should avoid using substitute but I feel it is essential to have it in my code as from a line in the xml file:

```
 <Gene-track_geneid>816394</Gene-track_geneid>
```

I want to take only the Id which here is `816394` can be any number (any number of digits) for other entries; so how can I avoid using `substitute`.

*Thanks in advance*

### ANSWER:

First, I would like to apologize to take so long to reply; as I started again from root to top for Perl and this time came clear with `use strict`, which helped me in maintaining the linear time. And also the use of `XML Parsers` is a good thing to do while handling large Xml files..

*Thanks all for help and suggestions*

Comment: `while` should read the file line by line so there should be no performance hit as it reads through the file... perhaps there's something else going on in `{do something}` which is causing the issue. Can we see the rest of your script.

Comment: @Joshua I have just added my actual code, have a look

Comment: You really should `use strict` as it helps control scoping which may contribute to memory leaks. perl will retain previously used memory that was allocated to a hash. Instead of `%values = ()` try `undef %values;`

Comment: @Joshua Sorry, but I haven't used `use strict` before in my Perl scripts. Can you please refer some good material on it; so I could make essential changes and will then post the new results.

Comment: You are parsing XML. I would strongly suggest you use an XML parser. XML::Twig is good, and has a purge method for freeing memory as you go.

Comment: What operating system are you on?  What version of Perl (perl -v)?  And what *filesystem* are you using?  In particular, is it a network filesystem?

Comment: @Sobrique I am exploring more such modules as suggested by @Schwern
And my OS is `32bit Win7 Professional`, Perl version `(v5.20.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int` and File system is `NTFS`

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment above, you should get into the habit of using the `strict` and `warnings` pragma's at the start of every script. `warnings` just picks up mistakes that might not be found until runtime. `strict` enforce a number of good rules including declaring all variables with `my`. The variable then exists only in the scope (typically the code block) it was declared in.

Try something like this and see if you get any improvement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %values;
my $line = 0;
open my $XML, '<', "file.xml" or die $!;
open my $TEMP, '>>', "temp.txt" or die $!;
while (<$XML>) {
    chomp;
    $line++;

    if (s/foo//gi) { $values{id} = $_; }
    elsif (s/foo//gi) { $values{type} = $_; }
    elsif (s/foo//gi) { $values{pattern} = $_; }

    if (keys(%values) == 3) {
        print $TEMP "$values{id}\t$values{type}\t$values{pattern}\n";
           undef %values;
    }

    # if ($line = ... 
}
close $TEMP;
```

*Ignore my one-line-if formatting, I did that for brevity. Format however you like*

The main thing I've done which I hope helps is declare the `%values` hash inside the `while` block, so it doesn't have a "global" scope, and then it's `undef`ine at the end of each block, which if I recall correctly should clear the memory it was using. Also opening and closing your output only once should cut down on a lot of unecessary operations.

Also just cleaned up a few things. Since you are acting on the topical `$_` variable, you can leave it out of operations like `chomp` (which now occurs only once at the beginning of the loop) and you regex substution.

**EDIT**

It just occured to me that you might be waiting multiple loops until `%values` reaches `3` in which case it will not work so I moved the `undef` back inside the `if`.

**MORE EDIT**

As has been commented below, you should look into installing and using an XML parser from cpan. If you for whatever reason are unable to use a module, a capturing regex might work better than a replacements... eg: `$var = /^<\/(\w+)>/` should capture <`this`>

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason I see why that code would take exponentially more time.  I don't see any memory leaks.  `%values` will not grow.  Looping over each line in a file does not depend on the file size only the line size.  I even made an XML file with 4 million lines in it from your linked XML data to test it.

My thoughts are...

- There's something you're not showing us (those regexes aren't real, `$start_time` is not initialized).
- <strike>You're on a wacky filesystem, perhaps a network filesystem.</strike> (OP is on NTFS)
- <strike>You're using a very old version of Perl with a bug.</strike> (OP is using Perl 5.20.1)

A poorly implemented network filesystem *could* slow down while reading an enormous file.  It could also misbehave because of how you're opening and closing temp.txt rapidly.  You could be chewing through file handles.  temp.txt should be opened once before the loop.  [@Joshua's improvement suggestions are good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236321/14660) (though the concern about `%values` is a red herring).

As also noted, you should not be parsing XML by hand.  For a file this large, use a [SAX parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) which works on the XML a piece at a time keeping the memory costs down, as opposed to a DOM parser which reads the whole file.  There are [many to choose from](https://metacpan.org/search?q=xml+sax&size=20).

Answer (score 1):

`while (<$fh>) {...}` doesn't reread the file from the start on each iteration, no

The most likely cause of your problem is that you're keeping data in memory on each iteration, causing memory usage to grow as you work your way through the file.  The slowdown comes in when physical memory is exhausted and the computer has to start paging out to virtual memory, ultimately producing a situation where you could be spending more time just moving memory pages back and forth between RAM and disk than on actual work.

If you can produce a brief, runnable test case which demonstrates your problem, I'm sure we can give more specific advice to fix it.  If that's not possible, just a description of your `{do something}` process could give us enough to go on.

*Edit after Edit 1 to question:*

Looking at the code posted, I suspect that your slowdown *may* be caused by how you're handling your output.  Closing and reopening the output file each time you add a line to it would definitely slow things down relative to if you just kept it open and, depending on your OS/filesystem combination, it may need to seek through the entire file to find the end to append.

Nothing else stands out to me as potentially causing performance issues, but a couple other minor points:

- After your regex substitutions, `$_` will never contain line ends (unless you explicitly include them in the `foo` patterns), so you can probably skip the `chomp $_;` lines.
- You should `open` the output file the same way as you `open` the input file (lexical filehandle, three-argument `open`) instead of doing it the old way.

Comment: @DaveSheroham I am not saving all of my data but just creating a file that has 3 columns (1 word each), and also I keep removing it as soon as it reaches 1000 rows (not mentioned in the code).

Comment: %values will be growing too. Writing out to a file doesn't occupy memory.

Comment: @Sobrique - I thought the same thing initially, but he's resetting it (`%values = ();`) after each write and, even without that, only three hash keys are ever assigned to, so new data would overwrite old data instead of the hash growing.

Comment: @DaveSheroham I got the point with the `chomp` but as I am removing the file when it reaches 1000 lines so even if that is the case it should then increase steadily and then when starting to write the new file it should drop back to normal timings. But it is not happening.